# Do Jews accept the Bible as being valid?

Tags: tanach, christianity, parshanut-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Jewish people have a collection of books which are the equivelant of the Christian Old Testament?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/do-jewish-people-have-a-collection-of-books-which-are-the-equivelant-of-the-chri)

The Bible has an "Old testament" and a "New Testament". Do Jews use the "Old Testament" of the Bible or do they have a separate book? Is the Bible considered a valid book to the Jews?

Comment: aliyah, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I've marked this question for possible closure, because it's essentially the same as the question linked in my previous comment, so I hope you'll take a look at that other question. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: That's funny, because my [bible](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Bbible&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just contains the [Tanach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanach) :-) I second Isaac's welcome. Have a look around (you might find [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8248/759) interesting) and don't be afraid to ask more questions!

Answer (score 2):

The Old Testament found in a Christian Bible consists of a translation from Hebrew (and in a few small sections, from Aramaic) of the text of the Jewish Bible. The customary ordering of the books is different. Christian translations, especially more contemporary ones, are open to conjecturing that scribal error crept in and suggesting emendations. But, yes, you're looking at something that aims to be a translated version of the same texts. In general, Jews learn the original text in the original language, consulting commentaries, rather than using translations into other languages. And there is huge body of tradition explaining the text and a long line of give-and-take among commentators that is very important to Jews studying the Bible.