# Why does Orthodox Judaism not believe in the New Testament?

Tags: christianity, orthodox

Why do Orthodox Jews not believe in the New Testament?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Jews accept the Bible as being valid?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/do-jews-accept-the-bible-as-being-valid)

Comment: Why should we accept it?

Comment: Why don't Christians believe in the Quran?

Comment: This is presumably a duplicate of [Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah), which is about what I (not an expert) think is probably the core tenet of the NT. Otherwise, it's unclear what the question is. Jews of all stripes certainly believe in the *existence* of the NT.

Comment: @IsaacMoses the core tenet of Christianity is the special status of Jesus (moshiach and God incarnate, *l'havdil*), but Paul, a significant author in their books, also makes other changes -- abolition of the *b'rit* probably being the main one.  Even without the Jesus claims that would be problematic.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, so the question really needs to specify whether it's asking about Jews' not believing in the truth of the NT, the value of the NT, the holiness of the NT, the truth of particular core claims of the NT, or whatever. It also, as DoubleAA suggests above, needs to include some indication of why one might expect Jews adopt whatever belief it is, since otherwise, there's no basis for the question, from the point of view of Judaism. I voted to close as a duplicate, but I now think that it really should be closed as Unclear.

Comment: @IsaacMoses that makes sense; I'd agree with "unclear" rather than 'dupe".

Comment: Yeah, straight up nonsensical. They don't believe the NT because it's not a Jewish text. Just like Christians don't believe the Quran because it's not a Christian text.

Comment: The question is being asked from a paradigm of the NT bring divine. This prompts the question of why we 'rejected' it. It is not a duplicate per se of general questions about what we have against Christianity. I think answers should address that paradigm, like @DoubleAA did, to explain how we didn't **reject** it; we **ignored** it. It was never given to us.

Answer (score 7):

Jews do not believe there's anything special about the Christian scriptures because they make claims counter to torah (like that God would abandon the covenant he made with Jews and impose new surprise requirements later).  God's torah is true, and any other document that contradicts it therefore doesn't reflect God's truth.

For why one of their most important claims is a non-starter for Jews, see [Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah).

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple reasons, far too many to explain in a simple answer. It mostly has to do with various new-testament proofs, that are either not proofs, or were not prophesized to be proofs. There are several important inconsistencies as well that are problematic from a jewish perspective (not just orthodox).

One of those is that mashiach needs to be from David's bloodline (e.g. [bereshit 49:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8244#v=10), [Yirmiyahu 33:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16030#v=17)) through Solomon (e.g. [Divrei Hayamim I 22:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16542#v=10). Unfortunately, from the two gospels that show bloodlines, one is through Maria, which is invalid to us because tribal descent is patrilineal ([Bamidbar 1:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9929/jewish/Chapter-1.htm#v=18)), and tribal descent can not be adopted (an adopted non-cohen child by a cohen is not given cohen-status) (and even it it could: the line is not through Solomon, but Nathan), and the line through Joseph goes through King Conyahu (Jeconia) that was cursed and kingship was taken away from him ([Yirmiyahu 22:30](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16019#v=30)).

There are various of such things: one of which is alleged virgin birth, which is not something than can be observed by onlookers (does a virginborn look any different from a nonvirginborn?) and goes against the principle of public signs from hashem.

Miracles were never part of the necessary conditions for proving someone is mashiach; the Torah even states that G'd will let false prophets perform miracles to test the jewish nation [devarim 13:2-6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9977#v=2); so we reject the claim that if someone is able to perform miracles, he **must** be the mashiach.

More importantly: the maschiach was supposed to rebuild the temple ([michah 4:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16190#v=1))(the physical one), whereas the temple was still standing in the time of the early gospel; and peace on earth did not happen ([michah 4:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16190#v=3),[Yeshayahu 2:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15933#v=4)); worse: the jewish people saw one of its worse destructions; the romans squashed all rebellion, destroyed our temple, and scattered us amonst the nations. There is not a 'he will come to finish the job' clausule in our texts.

All in all, it is best not to enter a discussion of such things. I personally have high respect for christians and have no interest in convincing them out of their belief. I just belief, as do most jews in my area, that christianity is for the christians, and judaism is for jews; those who were lost to us will find their way back, but generally each nation has its own G'dly-mission on this planet.

Comment: Is that so? I wish I had read the new testament. I was still in Isaiah. :(

Comment: Ah, the famous 'suffering servant' chapter. https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/counter-missionary/counter-missionary-seminar-topics/isaiah-53-explained/

Comment: ....to put it in a nutshell, ISRAEL was the Suffering Servant in those sections of Isaiah.

Answer (score 2):

Christians believe that Jesus was the Moshiach (Messiah), and that he will return to life at some point in time. However, one of the things that the Moshiach will do is eliminate war. Since Jesus did not do this, he could not have been the Moshiach. Since the New Testament claims that he *was* the Moshiach, to Orthodox Jews, this invalidates the entire New Testament.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25855/discussion-between-superplane-and-alyssa-gono).

Comment: "Messianic Judaism" is not Judaism, it's Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

1. The "Old" testament, whilst containing partly a history of recorded events and also writings of psalms etc. is primarily written by Prophets of G-d. It is part of our "tradition" that prophecy ended with Malachi, who is in the "old" testament. Anything after that is not "divine" and if it claims to contain prophecies, these are always considered false. This even includes the Maccabians, which may be historically accurate and they may even have been religiously observant but is not part of our "canonised" text.
2. Jesus is not accepted as "Moshiach", as he fails almost all the criteria. (Aside from being Jewish and possibly of the lineage of King David, he has failed every other aspect of what the Moshiach must do).

Comment: Maybe he'll come back from the dead and finish doing all the required things?

Comment: If he does we might then accept him as Messiah but still there is no "Trinity". The Messiah will be a person not a "son of G-d".