# Rav Yaakov Emden and the Survival of the Jewish people

Tags: sources-mekorot, miracle, golus-exile, rav-yaakov-emden

Rav Yaakov Emden says, *"By my life, the survival of the Jewish people in this golus is a greater miracle than the Splitting of the Sea"*

Where does he says this?

Comment: How do you know he says that?

Comment: A quick Google search yields [this article](http://jstandard.com/content/item/joseph_and_chanukah_thriving_against_all_odds/32060) by R' Howard Jachter: `As Rabbi Jacob Emden has commented, in the introduction to his siddur (prayer book): “By the life of my head,” the greatest miracle is the continued survival of the Jewish people. Rabbi Emden, writing in the eighteenth century, asserts that the miracle of Jewish survival in our prolonged exile is even greater than the miracle of the splitting of the Red Sea.`

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29742/1857 see bottom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [introduction to R' Ya'akov Emden's siddur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=13) (bottom of the page). R' Emden is continuing from his discussion of the persistent survival of the Jewish people through great adversity and the appropriate conclusions to draw from this regarding HaShem's involvement in the world and His care for the Jewish people:

> By the life of my soul! When I contemplated these wonders, they appeared greater to me than all the miracles and wonders that HaShem *Yisbarach* performed for our forefathers in Egypt, and the wilderness, and the Land of Israel.

Comment: If you want to know the exact location, it's it's in Sulam Bais Eil, (page 13, bottom of the first column in the print I usually see). Paragraph וידע right before the second os Aleph.