# Is burning in hot excrement a genuine possible punishment in gehinnom?

Tags: gehinnom, afterlife

> **מסכת גיטין נ"ז**:
>
> ...כל המלעיג על דברי חכמים נידון בצואה רותחת

Is this a genuine punishment that adherents of Orthodox Judaism believe to be carried out? Does it pertain to both Jews and none-Jews? and how long must one endure there?

Comment: "Where do we find sources describing this as an actual punishment?" You tell us. Obviously you found it somewhere, or you wouldn't be asking. The more info you include in a question that led you to ask it, the better answers you'll get, generally.

Comment: The article [“The Soul and the Afterlife”](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361897/jewish/The-Soul-and-the-Afterlife.htm) says

It must be understood that Gehinom is not a physical place and the descriptions given speak in human terms that we appreciate, nor is Gehinom a place for eternity, but a temporary—albeit terrible—place for the soul to be cleansed. In fact, the vast majority of souls do not stay in Gehinom for more than eleven months.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok You should expand on the contents of the link and give it as an answer.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76839/9215

Comment: Why would you assume there is **literally physical boiling excrement** in Gehinnom? Last time I checked Gehinnom wasn't a physical place.

Answer (score 2):

Rambam appears to offer a metaphorical interpretation of this statement:

**Introduction to Commentary to Mishnah**

> ואמרו כל המלעיג על דברי חכמים נידון בצואה רותחת ואין לך צואה רותחת
>   גדולה מן הכסילות אשר השיאתו להלעיג
>
> And they said "whoever mocks the words of the Sages is judged in
>   boiling excrement", and there is no greater boiling excrement than the
>   foolishness that entices one to mock.

Comment: Related Hebrew article: https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90/