# 9 year old Daughter Asked Me About god

Tags: theology, avodah-zarah

My 9 year old learned in Sunday School about how we don't pray to idols but couldn't quite understand how god was any different. I wasn't sure how to approach the topic because I didn't know what they had said. Any tips?

Comment: We also don't know what they had said, as I'm sure you realize

Comment: You may find the following answers useful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18653/15256

Comment: Call the teacher and ask what they said and discuss what you should answer.

Comment: If I’m understanding you correctly, are you asking how we know that G-d is real but idols aren’t? If so I think the link @Kazi provided should suffice.

Comment: Tell her that G-d does not have a body and is one. And since G-d does not have a body it would be impossible to make an idol and to worship based on the shape of G-d, since G-d lacks any shape or form.

Comment: See Kings 2 Ch. 19 v. 18 and really the whole story there where this question is addressed